# android Attempt to invoke virtual method Button.setOnClickListener on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, object, reference, null

i have a problem with this java class:

the error is :Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert_note);
```

before

```
nota = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ins_note); 
btn_add_nota = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add_note);
```